# Separating two CSS sheets within the same HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a HTML page with a series of javascripts and css files contained in the header like usual

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am making a site mobile compatible and have sources some online resources to achieve this. However with this code i need to link to another css file "apps.css". When i load my site the apps.css and original main.css files are clashing with each other and causing all sorts of problems. As both css files are quite large i am wondering if it is possible to reference only a single block of code to source only one of the css files.

For example:

I want this piece of HTML

```
<div>
<nav id="topMenu" role="navigation">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav-bar">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Pending Entries</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyStores", "Home")">My Stores</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")">Create New Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyEntries", "Home")">My Entries</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ImageGallery")">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

to read only this css file

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/app.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and to disregard the other main.css file, while the rest of my HTML reads the original main.css ignoring the apps.css

Comment: use a media query on an importing main sheet or on the link tag.

Answer (score 2):

To get apps.css to apply only to your code block, you should pick a class to apply to your HTML block, create a "CSS reset" rule for that class, and prefix the rules in apps.css with that same class. You should include both css files, but ensure that apps.css is after main.css.

This will only require you to change apps.css and you can leave main.css as-is. It is essential that apps.css included after main.css so that it can override the main.css rules for everything inside of elements with the .apps class.

In this case, you can apply the apps class to your div.

```
<div class="apps">
<nav id="topMenu" role="navigation">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav-bar">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Pending Entries</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyStores", "Home")">My Stores</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")">Create New Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyEntries", "Home")">My Entries</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ImageGallery")">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

In apps.css, every rule needs to be prefixed with ".apps ". Also, a "CSS Reset" style rule should be placed at the top of apps.css to negate the effect of the main.css.

```
.apps *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.apps table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are one option, but it sounds more like you need to review the fundamentals of CSS and fix that instead. The fact that both files are quite large is another red flag. If all you need is some list styling, why not just load that bit?

Since you only want #topMenu to use apps.css, you might prepend each statement in that file with `#topMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

As i said isherwood, you cannot hide a css , what you could do is personalize a partial div using that css when you want to use in that case

Comment: meant to be a comment?